# Django проблема iregex

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, django

Есть проблема, вернее пол проблемы, не понятно куда копать.

```
objects = Model.objects.filter(text_field__iregex = r'[[:<:]]{}'.format(search_word))
```

Довольно простой запрос.
Так вот на сервере все норм отрабатывает и находит записи. 
На локальной машине ошибка "'Illegal argument to a regular expression.'"

Если вместо `[[:<:]]` ставлю `\b`, то работает на локальной, перестает работать на сервере и ошибку при этом никакую не выдает, просто ноль записей находит.

Версии Django, и наборы пакетов стоят одинаковые. База MySQL.

Comment: Там разные библиотеки регулярных выражений. В версиях MySQL до 8 начальную границу слова можно найти только с помощью `[[:<:]]`, `\b` не будет работать. В `re` нужно использовать `\b`. Вообще, если нужна универсальная граница слова, можно попробовать что-то вроде `(^|[^A-Za-zА-Яа-яёЁ0-9_])` вместо этих шаблонов. Лучше, всё-таки, для каждой среды использовать свой шаблон, не надо изобретать "костыли".

Comment: Блин точно! Разные версии MySQL стоят. Да, конечно, лушче без костылей :) Спасибо!

Comment: Если есть возможность использовать MySQL v8.x, то используйте `\b` и там и в Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В MySQL и Python разные библиотеки регулярных выражений: в Python это `re`, в MySQL до версии 8.х это библиотека, основанная на регулярках POSIX, с дополнительными возможностями (такими как границы слова `[[:<:]]` и `[[:>:]]`).

`[[:<:]]` — это шаблон начальной границы слова, соответствующий правилам регулярок POSIX, и он "работает" в MySQL до версии 8.х. В MySQL 8.х, где реализована поддержка регулярных выражений с помощью более функциональной библиотеки ICU, границу слова можно найти с помощью `\b`, также как и в `re`.

Проверьте, какая версия MySQL используется в каждом случае, и для каждой среды используйте соответствующий шаблон.

Answer (score 0):

Используй две косых черты перед b и четыре косых черты, если используешь интерпретатор, типа PHP() или Python. Нужно заэкранировать экраны, иначе интерпритаторы, сжирают первую косую, и в регулярку попадает b, что не даёт результата.

**[[:<:]]** заменить на **\\b**

**[[:>:]]** заменить на **\\b**

в php:

```
<?php
$where = "regexp '[[:<:]] ."$custom_category." [[:>:]]'";
```

заменить на:

```
<?php
$where = "regexp '\\\\b" . $custom_category . "\\\\b'";
```